# HTTPResponse object -- JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-3.4, vonage

I've been trying to update a small Python library called [libpynexmo](https://github.com/marcuz/libpynexmo) to work with Python 3.

I've been stuck on this function:

```
def send_request_json(self, request):
    url = request
    req =  urllib.request.Request(url=url)
    req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
    try:
        return json.load(urllib.request.urlopen(req))
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

When it gets to this, json responds with:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
```

I read in a few places that for `json.load` you should pass objects (In this case an `HTTPResponse` object) with a `.read()` attached, but it doesn't work on `HTTPResponse` objects.

I'm at a loss as to where to go with this next, but being that my entire 1500 line script is freshly converted to Python 3, I don't feel like going back to 2.7.

Comment: See here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862770/python-3-let-json-object-accept-bytes-or-let-urlopen-output-strings

Comment: did you try passing it through 2to3?

Comment: @zmo - Did it manually so I could learn more.

Comment: @dano - Found that link earlier, but was unable to make his workaround apply to my situation.  I am unable to use .readall() on my HTTPResponse object.

Comment: @Chevron Why can't you use `readall`?

Comment: @Chevron, if you're trying to convert the json request object, then use this:  json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3, let json object accept bytes or let urlopen output strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862770/python-3-let-json-object-accept-bytes-or-let-urlopen-output-strings)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I recently wrote a small function to send Nexmo messages.  Unless you need the full functionality of the libpynexmo code, this should do the job for you.  And if you want to continue overhauling libpynexmo, just copy this code.  The key is utf8 encoding.

If you want to send any other fields with your message, the full documentation for what you can include with a nexmo outbound message [is here](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/sms-api/send-message)

Python 3.4 tested [Nexmo](http://www.nexmo.com) outbound (JSON):

```
def nexmo_sendsms(api_key, api_secret, sender, receiver, body):
    """
    Sends a message using Nexmo.

    :param api_key: Nexmo provided api key
    :param api_secret: Nexmo provided secrety key
    :param sender: The number used to send the message
    :param receiver: The number the message is addressed to
    :param body: The message body
    :return: Returns the msgid received back from Nexmo after message has been sent.
    """


    msg = {
        'api_key': api_key,
        'api_secret': api_secret,
        'from': sender,
        'to': receiver,
        'text': body
    }
    nexmo_url = 'https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json'
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(msg)
    binary_data = data.encode('utf8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(nexmo_url, binary_data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    result = json.loads(response.readall().decode('utf-8'))
    return result['messages'][0]['message-id']
```

Answer (score 47):

Facing the same problem I solve it using decode()

```
...
rawreply = connection.getresponse().read()
reply = json.loads(rawreply.decode())
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary?

Comment: Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862770/python-3-let-json-object-accept-bytes-or-let-urlopen-output-strings) for an explanation

Answer (score 13):

I met the problem as well and now it pass

```
import json
import urllib.request as ur
import urllib.parse as par

html = ur.urlopen(url).read()
print(type(html))
data = json.loads(html.decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are getting a [HTTPResponse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPResponse), you can use [Tornado.escape](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/branch2.2/escape.html) and its `json_decode()` to convert the JSON string into a dictionary:

```
from tornado import escape

body = escape.json_decode(body)
```

From the manual:

> *tornado.escape.json_decode(value)*
>
> Returns Python objects for the given JSON string.