# Python 3.4.1 - Reading HTTP Request Data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, urllib

I'm fairly new to Python and I'm trying to execute a HTTP Request to a URL that returns JSON. The code, I have is:

```
url = "http://myurl.com/"
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
data = response.read()
```

I'm getting an error reading: "'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'". I searched around, but haven't found a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: This can't be your real code. In your real code, try `print(type(response))` and/or `print(repr(response))` to see what you've got in place of the `http.client.HTTPResponse` that this code returns. And then show us your real code and we can show you why you've got that.

Comment: The most obvious mistake that would cause this is `response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()`, so you're calling `read()` on the result of `read()`, but there are countless other ways you could do this, and we can't guess which one you did without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862770/python-3-let-json-object-accept-bytes-or-let-urlopen-output-strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library easier to use:

```
import requests
data = requests.get('http://example.com').text
```

or, if you need the raw, undecoded bytes,

```
import requests
data = requests.get('http://example.com').content
```