# Python3 - TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'

Tags: json, python-3.x, urllib

I'm a python beginner (working only with python3 so far) and I'm trying to present some code working the curses library to my classmates.

I got the code from a python/curses tutorial and it runs without problems in python2. In python3 it doesn't and I get the error in title.
Searching through the already asked questions, I found several solutions to this, but since being a absolute beginner with coding, I have no idea how to execute those in my specific code.

This is the code working in python2 :

```
import curses
from urllib2 import urlopen
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from simplejson import loads


def get_new_joke():

joke_json = loads(urlopen('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random').read())
return HTMLParser().unescape(joke_json['value']['joke']).encode('utf-8')
```

Using the new modules in python3:

```
import curses
import json
import urllib
from html.parser import HTMLParser



def get_new_joke():

    joke_json = loads(urlopen('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random').read())
    return HTMLParser().unescape(joke_json['value']['joke']).encode('utf-8')
```

Furthermore I tried to include this solution into my code:
[Python 3, let json object accept bytes or let urlopen output strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862770/python-3-let-json-object-accept-bytes-or-let-urlopen-output-strings)

```
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random')
str_response = joke_json.readall().decode('utf-8')
obj = json.loads(str_response)
```

Tried around for hours now, but it tells me "json" ist not defined.

Comment: Are you doing `import json` in your second solution?

Comment: @AmauryMedeiros is absolutely right. An additional note: In Python 2.6+ you do not need `simplejson`. Instead you can use `import json` as well. It is part of the Python Standard Library.

Comment: yes, the imports are the same as used above (python3 version)