# Python3 PUT string, not bytes

Tags: json, string, python-3.x, put

I am trying to get Python3 to PUT json info in string format to an API. And I want to do it without

```
import requests
```

Thus far I am stuck with this code:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import json
url = "http://www.example.com"
DATA = json.dumps({'grades': {"math": "92", "chem": "39"}})
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data=DATA, method='PUT')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

Naturally this raises the error:

```
raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str.
```

To get rid of the error I can do:

```
DATA= str.encode(DATA)
```

But this turns my data into bytes format, instead of string that I want to put up. Is there a way to PUT up strings without importing "requests"?(importing anything that comes with python install is OK). Or can I PUT up a *.json file?

Essentially I am trying to do the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862770/python-3-let-json-object-accept-bytes-or-let-urlopen-output-strings).

Comment: Python 3 defines str variables as unicode and hence the reason you are seeing the raised error.

Comment: The error message says it all. It wants bytes. You can't send Unicode strings without encoding them.