# How to apply integration tests to a Flask RESTful API

Tags: python, flask, integration-testing, flask-restful, werkzeug

*[As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/46369945/1021819, the title should refer to integration tests rather than unit tests]*

Suppose I'd like to test the following Flask API (from [here](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.5/quickstart.html#a-minimal-api)):

```
import flask
import flask_restful

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
api = flask_restful.Api(app)

class HelloWorld(flask_restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Having saved this as `flaskapi.py` and run it, in the same directory I run the script `test_flaskapi.py`:

```
import unittest
import flaskapi
import requests

class TestFlaskApiUsingRequests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_hello_world(self):
        response = requests.get('http://localhost:5000')
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), {'hello': 'world'})


class TestFlaskApi(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = flaskapi.app.test_client()

    def test_hello_world(self):
        response = self.app.get('/')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Both the tests pass, but for the second test (defined in the `TestFlaskApi`) class I haven't yet figured out how to assert that the JSON response is as expected (namely, `{'hello': 'world'}`). This is because it is an instance of `flask.wrappers.Response` (which is probably essentially a Werkzeug Response object (cf. http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/wrappers/)), and I haven't been able to find an equivalent of the `json()` method for `requests` [Response](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response) object.

How can I make assertions on the JSON content of the second `response`?

Comment: What about functional tests, you don't expect to run a service separately for running your tests in separate process do you? How will you mock the database, I believe this should be functional tests which just mock request by passing object directly to flask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask Unittest for Post Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44892061/flask-unittest-for-post-method)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've found that I can get the JSON data by applying `json.loads()` to the output of the `get_data()` method:

```
import unittest
import flaskapi
import requests
import json
import sys

class TestFlaskApiUsingRequests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_hello_world(self):
        response = requests.get('http://localhost:5000')
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), {'hello': 'world'})


class TestFlaskApi(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = flaskapi.app.test_client()

    def test_hello_world(self):
        response = self.app.get('/')
        self.assertEqual(
            json.loads(response.get_data().decode(sys.getdefaultencoding())), 
            {'hello': 'world'}
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Both tests pass as desired:

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.019s

OK
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Comment: "Status: Flask API is not currently under active development." from https://github.com/flask-api/flask-api

Comment: @TheGrimmScientist The OP is using flask-restful, not flask-api

Answer (score 41):

Flask provides a test_client you can use in your tests:

```
from source.api import app
from unittest import TestCase

class TestIntegrations(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()

    def test_thing(self):
        response = self.app.get('/')
        assert <make your assertion here>
```

[Flask Testing Docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/#the-first-test)

Comment: (Posted as an answer to help others landing here see a cleaner way to write these tests)

Comment: Clean and consice.

Comment: @TheGrimmScientist The provided link to the docs is outdated. Maybe you want to update it to https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/#the-first-test ?

Answer (score 24):

What you're doing there is not unit testing. In every case, when using the requests library or the flask client, you're doing [integration testing](http://www.agilenutshell.com/episodes/41-testing-pyramid) as you make actual http calls to the endpoints and test the interaction.

Either the title of the question or the approach is not accurate.

Answer (score 2):

With Python3, I got the error `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not bytes`. It is required to decode:

```
# in TestFlaskApi.test_hello_world
self.assertEqual(json.loads(response.get_data().decode()), {'hello': 'world'})
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862770/python-3-let-json-object-accept-bytes-or-let-urlopen-output-strings) gives an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `response` object from `test_client` has a `get_json` method.

There's no need for converting the response to json with `json.loads`.

```
class TestFlaskApi(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = flaskapi.app.test_client()

    def test_hello_world(self):
        response = self.app.get("/")
        self.assertEqual(
            response.get_json(),
            {"hello": "world"},
        )
```