# Python: Build DataFrame from parts of JSON response

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to develop an application to retrieve stock prices (in JSON) and then do some analysis on them. My problem is with getting the JSON response into a pandas DataFrame where I can work. Here is my code:

```
'''
References
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862770/python-3-let-json-object-  accept-bytes-or-let-urlopen-output-strings
'''
import json
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen

#set API call
url = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/AAPL.json?start_date=2017-01-01&end_date=2017-01-31"

#make call and receive response
response = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
dataresponse = json.loads(response)

#check incoming
#print(dataresponse)

df = pd.read_json(dataresponse)

print(df)
```

The application errors at `df = pd.read_json...` with error *TypeError: Expected String or Unicode*.

So I reckon this is the first hurdle.

The second is getting where I need to. The JSON response contains only two arrays I am interested in, `column_names` and `data`. How do I extract only these two and put into a pandas DataFrame?

Comment: `pd.read_json` takes a JSON string directly, so do this: `pd.read_json(response)`

Answer (score 5):

To answer your first question, `pd.read_json` takes a JSON string directly, so you should be doing this:

```
pd.read_json(response)
```

---

But instead, considering how the data is structured, it's best to first convert the JSON string to a dictionary containing the data:

```
d = json.loads(response)
```

Then simply build the dataframe from `d['dataset']['data']` and `d['dataset']['column_names']`:

```
pd.DataFrame(data=d['dataset']['data'], columns=d['dataset']['column_names'])
```